# How can I convert a JSON string into an object with fields in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, json

Here is what I have now:

```
 console.log(JSON.stringify(errorParam))
 {"data":{"message":"{\"ErrorLine\":113,\"ErrorMessage\":\"Authentication Failed\",\"ErrorNumber\":50004,\"ErrorProcedure\":\"start_test\"}"},"status":400,"statusText":"Bad Request"}
```

I know about JSON.stringify but how can I convert this back into an object from a string?

Comment: `JSON.parse()` is what you need.

Comment: simply you can use JSON.Parse(errorParam)

Comment: JavaScript objects do not have "fields". They have "properties".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I know about JSON.stringify but how can I convert this back into an
>   object from a string?

Use `JSON.parse`

```
console.log(JSON.parse('{"data":{"message":"{\"ErrorLine\":113,\"ErrorMessage\":\"Authentication Failed\",\"ErrorNumber\":50004,\"ErrorProcedure\":\"start_test\"}"},"status":400,"statusText":"Bad Request"}'));
```